# Unit Deviance on test set R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, train, deviance

I am evaluating a set of predictions coming from different models against a set of actual values in a regression problem.
I do not want to use the mean squared error as my evaluation metric because my values are not normally distributed. I would like to actually use the deviance which extends this concept.
For example, the Poisson deviance is defined as 2(y * log(y/mu) - y + mu) where y are the actual values and the predicted ones.
In R, there is the `deviance` function, however this is applied to a `glm` object and therefore it will be calculated on the training set. Moreover I am not necessarily dealing with GLMs only. Do I need to define these functions manually for each distribution I need, or, these functions are already coded in some libraries?

Comment: MSE isn’t restricted to when you have normal error terms.

Comment: Can you please explain this to me a little bit more in details? I was under the impression the `MSE` minimizes the squared distances which corresponds to the normal likelihood.

Comment: The parameter estimates from optimizing square loss is the maximum likelihood estimator when the error term is normal, but you don't need normal errors for the square loss argmin to satisfy the Gauss-Markov theorem assumptions. In fact, square loss is a perfectly valid loss function for a binary classification problem! (It's called the Brier score, and it is a strictly proper scoring rule, just like cross-entropy.)

Comment: Would the MSE be a good loss function even when error terms are Poisson or Tweedie distributed?